# Serializing a CTypedPtrList in MFC Does Not Save the Data in the List

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

When I try to serialize a CTypedPtrList and then retrieve that list from the file, the number of objects in the list are saved, but not the actual data in the objects.

For example, if I were to save to file and then load from file, I could cycle through all four entries, but none of the variables would have their data in them.

Here is the applicable code.

LEDFrame.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "afx.h"

#define NUMLAYERS 12
#define NUMROWS 8
#define NUMCOLUMNS 12

class LEDFrame :
    public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(LEDFrame)  // DECLARE_SERIAL macro call to enable serialization of CObjects
public:
    bool data[NUMLAYERS][NUMROWS][NUMCOLUMNS]; // this holds one frame of the animation
    int m_FrameOnTime; // this holds how long the frame is on for, a value of 1 is 10 ms
    LEDFrame();
    ~LEDFrame();
};

typedef CTypedPtrList<CObList, LEDFrame*> CLEDFrameList; // this is the list of frames, CTypedPtrlList can be shared between document and view
```

LEDFrame.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LEDFrame.h"

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(LEDFrame, CObject, 0) // implement_serial macro call for serialization

LEDFrame::LEDFrame()
{
}

LEDFrame::~LEDFrame()
{
}
```

LEDCubeDoc.h

```
public:
    virtual void Serialize(CArchive& ar);
private:
    CLEDFrameList myLEDFrameList;
```

LEDCubeDoc.cpp

```
void CLEDCubeDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    TRACE("Entering CLEDCubeDoc::Serialize");
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        // TODO: add storing code here
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: add loading code here
    }
    myLEDFrameList.Serialize(ar);
}
```

LEDCubeView.h

```
public:
    CLEDFrameList* myViewLEDFrameList;  // a pointer to the documents myLEDFrameList, this edits myLEDFrameList in the doc
```

I think that it may not be saving the list correctly to disk.  This is because when I look at the saved file it is only 22 bytes.

I am including "afxtempl" in stdafx.h.

My program is based on modules 10 and 11 of the MFC tutorial at www.tenouk.com.  The URL is http://www.tenouk.com/cplusplusnmfc.html

Would you please help me rectify this issue so I can serialize my CTypedPtrList?

Thank you,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any declaration of `LEDFrame::Serialize`, so I guess you haven't implemented it. This means, the serialize-method of `CObject` will be called, and how should that function know, what's inside your class?!

BTW: You have to call `myLEDFrameList.Serialize(ar);` in both cases of `ar.IsStoring` - one is for storing, the else-part is for loading. If you need a special order for loading or have to call some functions to help loading, you can do that here.

Comment: I thought of adding LEDFrame::Serialize, but what would it serialize?  myLEDFrameList is part of LEDCubeDoc, not LEDFrame.  I thought that LEDFrame::Serialize() would be called because of the statement:

    typedef CTypedPtrList<CObList, LEDFrame*>

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629476/mfc-serialization?rq=1